# Best HTML5 structure for a layout where the title/header is outside the article tag

Tags: html, wai-aria

I have a layout that gives me the choice of either:

1. including the sidebar within the article tag, even though it's not specific to the article
2. having the title outside the article tag

Currently I have the title outside the article tag, but the validator tells me that the itemprop="headline" isn't part of any item.

What would be the best way to structure this? Is there a `for` attribute for relating a title with an article?

If you're wondering what type of layout would force me to make this choice, it's a full-width heading section, then article and sidebar below.

**Edit**

Simplified code

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <header class="article-header" itemprop="headline">
        <h1>This heading section spans the width of the page</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <nav class="submenu">
            <p>The submenu is here in the markup so that it appears above the content on mobiles, but it gets pulled to the side on wider screens.</p>
        </nav>
        <article class="content">
            <p>Article content...</p>
        </article>
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <p>This sidebar is not related specifically to the article on the page.</p>
        </aside>
    </div><!-- .content-wrap -->
</div><!-- .page-wrap -->
```

Comment: Did you omit the whole Microdata from your example, or are you only using this single `itemprop` attribute? And why are you using the WAI-ARIA tag (there is no WAI-ARIA included in your example nor do you mention it)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the heading *outside* of the section it belongs to.

So if the `h1` is the heading for the content of the `article`, it needs to be a child of the `article`. Otherwise, the document outline would be incorrect (→ there would be a superfluous/needless entry, created by the `article`):

```
1. This heading section spans the width of the page
  1.1 (implicit heading from the 'article' element)
```

Note: If the sub-menu (`nav`) is for navigating the `article` (for example, like the ToC of an Wikipedia article), it should also be a child of the `article`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of wraping your page in this:

```
<div class="page-wrap">...</div>
```

Wrap it in this:

```
<body>...</body>
```

I've never used itemprop="headline". It's a new  HTML5 attribute. It is not supported in many browsers. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_(HTML)#Support

Here is an article on microdata (which is what itemprop is). http://html5doctor.com/microdata/

This Stackoverflow question explains why you can't add Javascript support for microdata. [Add microdata using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923447/add-microdata-using-javascript)

So you could just use WAI ARIA. It works like this: http://mcdlr.com/wai-aria-cheatsheet/

Why do you have a sub-menu? Where is the main menu? You should include your main menu in your header if your title doesn't take up too much space.